# Правильное использование регулярных выражений в nginx

Tags: nginx

Согласно [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/313666/) автора Nginx, лучше избегать регулярных выражений и параметра "if". Тогда, имея такое выражение

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|tiff|gif|webp|xml|html|yml|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|rtf|pdf|txt|js|css|bmp|pnm|pbm|ppm)$ {
access_log off;
expires 30d;
}
```

лучше выполнить его таким образом

```
location .jpg {
    expires 30d;
}
location .jpeg {
    expires 30d;
}
location .png {
    expires 30d;
}
location .tiff {
    expires 30d;
}
location .gif {
    expires 30d;
}
location .webp {
    expires 30d;
}
location .xml {
    expires 30d;
}
location .html {
    expires 30d;
}
location .yml {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ogg {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ogv {
    expires 30d;
}
location .svg {
    expires 30d;
}
location .svgz {
    expires 30d;
}
location .eot {
    expires 30d;
}
location .otf {
    expires 30d;
}
location .woff {
    expires 30d;
}
location .woff2 {
    expires 30d;
}
location .mp4 {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ttf {
    expires 30d;
}
location .rss {
    expires 30d;
}
location .atom {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ico {
    expires 30d;
}
location .zip {
    expires 30d;
}
location .tgz {
    expires 30d;
}
location .gz {
    expires 30d;
}
location .rar {
    expires 30d;
}
location .bz2 {
    expires 30d;
}
location .doc {
    expires 30d;
}
location .xls {
    expires 30d;
}
location .exe {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ppt {
    expires 30d;
}
location .tar {
    expires 30d;
}
location .mid {
    expires 30d;
}
location .midi {
    expires 30d;
}
location .wav {
    expires 30d;
}
location .rtf {
    expires 30d;
}
location .pdf {
    expires 30d;
}
location .txt {
    expires 30d;
}
location .js {
    expires 30d;
}
location .css {
    expires 30d;
}
location .bmp {
    expires 30d;
}
location .pnm {
    expires 30d;
}
location .pbm {
    expires 30d;
}
location .ppm {
    expires 30d;
}
```

**Так ли это?**

Comment: Не совсем по теме вопроса, но я считаю, что в такой ситуации принципиально неверен сам подход. Если позволяет движок сайта, то лучше вынести все статические файлы в отдельные папочки (например `static` для родных файлов сайта и `media` для пользовательских загрузок) и тогда можно будет написать простое и элегантное `location /static/ { root /path/to/static; expires 30d; }`

Comment: @andreymal, к сожалению это нельзя сделать с Битрикс. Но решение и впрямь хорошее.

Comment: Нет. То что вы написали полная бессмыслица. Правильно например положить картинки в папку `images` и использовать `location /images/`

Comment: Впрочем вряд ли этот несчастный location который копипастят ужет лет 15 станет узким местом. Так что оставьте его как есть

Answer (score 1):

В вашем location вы не используете if, в нем всего лишь регулярка и создавать такие location можно.

Относительно нежелательности if вот ссылка на [статью](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Ваш случай не относится к описанному.

Относительно регулярных выражений в документации написано, что если есть возможность использовать префиксные выражения типа ^~ или точные совпадения = то лучше их использовать потому что они быстрее и менее ресурсоемкие. Именно поэтому в приоритете обрабатываются сначала они и только в конце регулярки.